# The right verb about satisfying or not someone's right in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

> They are going to do this surgery on the man. The man has *right* to be
>   informed about the side effects of the surgery. The man is *entitled* to be informed on that. They don't give him that information. They ____ the man's right to be informed on the side effects. That is wrong. They should ____ the man's right to be informed on the side effects.

When we are talking in such contexts of such kinds of right or entitlements, what verbs are good to use?

On the one hand, do we *violate, break,* or *contravene* the patient's right to be informed on the side effects of his surgery?

On the other hand, do we *satisfy, respect,* or *fulfil* one's right to be informed on the side effects of his surgery?

Or maybe other verbs?

**We don't know why they don't inform the man of the side effects; it can be because they are too ignorant, or for their own interests.**

Comment: Personally, and speaking from Britain, I would use ***neglect*** and ***respect***.  Americans, I suspect may incline differently.

Comment: I think the most idiomatic are (2) '**observe**', or '**comply with**' if one is being more clinical / legal-sounding, _and_ (1)  '**disregard**', or '**violate**' if one is being more litigious.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But we do not know that they did "disregard" his rights. Most likely, they simply forgot. I think the OP should tell us why he was not informed - that would determine the best words to use.

Comment: @WS2: **disregard**: the fact of showing no care or respect for something [CED].  disregard: To show no evidence of attention concerning (something): conduct that disregards risks to others.
3. To treat without proper respect or attentiveness. [AHD]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ***neglect*** v. OED sense 2. *transitive. To **disregard**; to pay little or no respect or attention to; to slight, leave unnoticed*. Many other senses of neglect are given, similar in meaning. So I'll happily call it a draw.

Comment: @WS2 No; this is non-negotiable (though I'm not in a competition, just wanting to score points. Reliable answers are what matters.) They disregarded his rights. By at least one totally acceptable sense of the word. Insisting on a favourite definition is unscholarly.

Comment: @WS2 I added something about your point.

Comment: Then I think "neglect" is the best word to use. @Edwin probably will not agree with me, but I believe "disregard" would (perhaps only slightly) carry an implication that they chose to ignore the rules.

Comment: Are those your own words in the blockquote, or someone else's?

Comment: @WS2 'Did not comply with' is incontestable. Note that I did _not_ say that 'disregard' does not contain a connotation of deliberate avoidance; other senses almost always give connotations. That does not license 'But we do not know that they did "disregard" his rights.' Yes we do. Also, 'neglect' carries this connotation (3. to ignore or disregard: _she neglected his frantic signals_.) [[Collins]9https://www.thefreedictionary.com/neglect).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I would agree that "neglect" is wide ranging and could involve the deliberate as well as simple ignorance. I am well aware that "disregard" can too. But I believe it is more skewed to the knowing than the unknowing.

Comment: @Spencer My own words.

Answer (score 1):

The doctors flouted the man's right to be informed.They should have acceded to it.

> Flout means to violate a rule  and accede means to agree to a rule.

See the links.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flout.

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/accede

Comment: "Flout" seems far too strong, and suggests it was a deliberate. Perhaps someone simply forgot to tell him. Hence my choice of "neglect" - see my comment under the question. And "accede" conveys quite the wrong sense too, I believe. One "accedes" to a demand.

Answer (score -1):

I think all your suggested words are good. The two that came to my mind when reading it were *breach* and *enforce*.

**Breach**

> an act of breaking or failing to observe a law, agreement, or code of
> conduct.
>
> "a breach of confidence"
>
> "they alleged breach of copyright"
>
> synonyms: contravention · violation · breaking · non-observance ·
> infringement · transgression · neglect · dereliction · failure to
> observe · non-compliance with · infraction · delict

**Enforce**

> compel observance of or compliance with (a law, rule, or obligation).
>
> "the role of the police is to enforce the law"
> synonyms: impose · apply · carry out · administer · implement · bring to bear · discharge
> · fulfil · execute · prosecute · effectuate · force · compel · exact ·
> extort · demand · insist on · require · necessitate · constrain
>
> cause (something) to happen by necessity or force.
>
> "there is no outside agency to enforce cooperation between the players"
>
> synonyms: compulsory · obligatory · mandatory · involuntary · forced · exacted ·
> coerced · imposed · demanded · required · requisite · stipulated ·
> contractual · binding · necessitated · necessary · unavoidable ·
> inescapable · obliged · impelled · constrained · dictated · ordained ·
> prescribed · de rigueur

Definitions from bing: [breach](https://www.bing.com/search?q=breach) and [enforce](https://www.bing.com/search?q=enforce).

Comment: Both of these words seem inappropriate, and too legalistic, to me - though I am not the person who downvoted. My comment appears under the question.